# The new flagging dialog gets in the way

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-dialog, close-dialog

The old flagging dialog box politely "stepped aside" or wasn't so big that it prevented a quick re-scan of a post and possibly a copy/paste of things in the post you wanted to highlight to the mods.

The improved flagging dialog hides the post being flagged. Now, with all these new flagging options, it's sometimes necessary to have a quick re-read to make sure you're picking the flag reason that matches best. If you've started typing in the "other" box, then you have to select/copy, close the dialog, re-read, re-open, etc, etc.

It kinda gets in the way.

It would be nice if the box

- were moved down a bit, to directly under the last line of text in a post (provided there was space available, perhaps); or
- were draggable so users could move it out of the way

This is also a problem with similar dialogs such as the closure dialog. It's particularly problematic with the [Close as Duplicate Dialog](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/when-selecting-possible-duplicates-can-the-popup-dialog-be-made-so-it-doesnt-b) as it's quite possible you'll want to review the question or click links to suggested duplicates in the comments, which might be blocked by the big overlay.

Comment: It actually comes up in the current center of the window. (Try scrolling down the page, then clicking flag. Not saying this should or shouldn't be changed, just pointing out the behaviour is a bit different than you think.)

Comment: @jon - I guess that's a bit of a workaround.

Comment: @jon ~ Talk about a hack ...

Comment: It seems like there has to be somebody around here smart enough to be able to figure out how to drag something around without using jQuery.

Answer (score 16):

Browsers have gotten sufficiently not garbage in the <sub>(checks)</sub> two years since this request came in that we revisited it as part of the other dialog changes.

Starting with the next build the flagging and closing popups will be dragable (the "title" at the top is the handle in both cases).

Comment: Is there a way to make this more intuitive? It's not immediately obvious that the dialog is draggable.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Yeah, we'll probably add a bar or something; couldn't quite decide what, and since it already *works* didn't see a reason not to ship it.  For now the indicator is only that the cursor changes.

Comment: "grips" are a standard way to hint at that: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-to-visualize-the-possibility-of-dragndrop/9261#9261 not sure how well it'd work with the style of the box, especially making it *less* cluttered

Comment: @KevinMontrose, could you give me a little hint as to how [I can piggy-back](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) onto this functionality? Apparently just adding the `handle` class to my `h2` isn't enough...

Comment: @Benjol There's a method `StackExchange.helpers.bindMovablePopups()` that's called when popups are loaded.

Comment: @KevinMontrose, thanks! Now updated to V1.2.8

Answer (score 7):

A possible alternative that I used for my [AutoComment](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) script is to add a 'seethrough' link. When you hover over it, you can 'see through' the popup.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the work that goes into a lot of these GM scripts, but I often feel they're a cop out for certain UX annoyances that should be fixed by the Team.

Comment: @Kev, maybe. I see it as off-the-records beta-testing of potential new functionality. Often they get official sanction, sometimes they get adopted.

Comment: That was the first thing that popped into my mind :P

Comment: I want this for blouses

Answer (score 0):

This requires pulling in a large jQuery UI dependency, and given that I think jQuery UI is pretty crappy and bloated.. unlikely.

Comment: *gasps in horror*. Don't listen to him jQuery, just turn away

Comment: no no, he said jQueryUI ... I think that's fine @Michael

Comment: @drachenstern Oh! Ok, that's fine. I thought SO depended on jQuery already, I was a little confused where the sudden dependency came from

Comment: @MichaelMrozek :p ;)

Comment: but it's already there. you're already including it. I opened up javascript console in FF and Chrome and ran the line above and it made the dialog draggable

Comment: to confirm i wasn't crazy i tried it again... it didn't work on this MSO post. I tried on the first question I saw on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720597/profile-bug-error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-x) and it didn't work. So I ran it on the page I ran it on earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string/878704#878704) and it worked. **So** if the UI is not intended to be included, is it a bug that it's being included on *some* pages?

Comment: it is also possible just to include the jQuery UI draggable portion across Google's CDN without having to include the whole jQuery UI library

Comment: if you view the source here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string/878704#878704) you'll see `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` at the top, being explicitly included. But it isn't being included on all pages.

Comment: @Kip I think it's included to use for the bounty slider

Comment: Given that you're pulling in 300k of script, 29k of minified jQueryUI for the draggable bits is a drop in the ocean. Methinks you haven't used the UI bits recently, and "crappy" is a bit unfair. Either way as I also highlighted that dialogue does get in the way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/new-flagging-dialogue-gets-in-the-way. This makes flagging a pretty awkward experience.

Comment: @kev I'm about to fire someone unless they remove that jQuery UI dependency (for bounties), so consider it gone.

Comment: Fair enough, but at least consider fixing that dialogue so it doesn't get in the way. it really slows down the review process.

Comment: @Jeff: Did you change your mind, or why is that calendar on the profile for the consecutive days also jQueryUI dependent?

Comment: @bobby I believe that only appears for the current user and devs/mods, so it's less objectionable