# Could we make the new flagging dialog draggable maybe?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, flags, flag-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [New flagging dialogue gets in the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/new-flagging-dialogue-gets-in-the-way)

I like the [new and improved flagging dialog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), but could you maybe make it draggable? It covers up the item that you are trying to flag, which you might need to refer back to after reading the close reasons, or while writing a comment to the mod in "other" field.

I know you can just close the dialog and then hit flag again, but being draggable would be convenient, and with jQuery it's literally as easy as:

```
$('.popup').draggable()
```