# Deleted comments appearing in global inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

This appears to have been [mentioned before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox) however, I think the problem still exists.

I commented on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/could-we-make-the-new-flagging-dialog-draggable-maybe/75282#75282) and someone has replied to me but the comment has been deleted. The same thing happened on another question two days ago, this is still also appearing in the global inbox.

I can see from the comments in the question linked at the top others have also mentioned this bug returning.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been going over the inbox code (that deals with comments anyway) with a fine toothed comb and found a couple of issues.

First, your problem wasn't a deletion.

Kip's comment

> if you view the source here
>   (stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string/…)
>   you'll see  at
>   the top, being explicitly included.
>   But it isn't being included on all
>   pages.

Was originally in reply to you, but was subsequently editted to drop the `@xiao`.  We weren't catching this case (related: if you added an `@somebody` they weren't getting the notice either).

There was also a bug around deleting comments on a post that were in explicit reply to the owner of that post (`@Kevin` on this answer, for instance).

These problems have been fixed and will go out with our next build.

Comment: always doing my part to break the system in creative ways!