# Deleted Comments still appear in the notification inbox

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, deleted-comments

The [bug where the Deleted Comment appear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75374/deleted-comments-appearing-in-global-inbox) in the notification inbox has recently started occurring for me.

This is what I see now:

[image]

The circled comments links to: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/3667?noredirect=1, But there is no such comment on the question, or any of the answers.

There is also this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/why-is-there-a-comment-in-my-inbox-that-doesnt-exist) which just gives the cause of the bug, but doesn't go into whether the bug is solved or not.

Comment: Clearly it is not solved; if a bug is not explicitly marked as solved and you just encountered it, it is not solved and you don't need to open a new post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [the first post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75374/deleted-comments-appearing-in-global-inbox) is tagged as status-completed, so as I understand it, the developers think this bug is resolved.

Comment: Ah, I missed the first post reference. Vote retracted.

Comment: And TBH, I had noticed this as well.

Comment: AFAIK you can see the new notification comment even if it was  deleted, are you sure is it still present in your inbox ?

Comment: @Bala: sorry, what? If you can see the notification for the comment in your inbox, it is visible in your inbox. Did you mean after a reload of the page?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes after the page reload

Comment: Once you read inbox item it will stay there forever, even if the related post or comment is deleted. Only if the comment/post is deleted before you click the box to read the notification, it will cause the notification to disappear.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I have not read/Seen the deleted post. It still appears in my inbox;

Comment: OK, I left a comment few seconds ago and deleted it. I'm 99% sure you don't have inbox item for it, but after you read the item leading to this comment, I can delete it and the item will stay.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I sort of see the comment; I see 11 comments even though there are only 10 comments on the question http://imgur.com/4yEaK3U; Further more I'm sure that if you comment on some other question of mine, I'll see the deleted comment.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe still, you don't see the deleted comment itself, right? That's my point. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard when there are multiple comments on one question you don't see them separately; you only see the latest one and the number of comments.that's what happens when you deleted the comment and added a new one. To really reproduce this post an comment on some of my other question and delete it. I will see it e

Comment: Done, I've posted a comment on your other question here on Meta then deleted it. Did you get notification?