# Has the Bounty Slider Changed?

Tags: support, user-interface, bounties

I was going to add a bounty on my question but has the bounty slider changed to a drop down box? I was using IE7 and have Windows XP SP3.

So I was wondering about the bounty slider change.

Comment: I don't get it. This says "This change was made. Was this change made?" It's not clear what sort of response you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, the answer is obviously yes.  Bounty amounts are now selected via a dropdown list rather than a jquery-ui slider.  This was done to remove the dependency on jquery-ui.

Answer (score 4):

Based on a [recent comment Jeff made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/could-we-make-the-new-flagging-dialog-draggable-maybe/75282#comment-182490), I suspect that the bounty slider was turned into a drop-down to remove the jQuery UI dependency that the slider created.