# Privilege wiki pages out of date (showing old design and description)

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, privileges-page

Found some wiki pages for privileges that are now out of date due to recent (and not so recent?) changes over the Stack Exchange network.

I'll list those I found, though I'm sure that on closer look we can find more.

[Privilege page for setting a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties): (**already done by Yi Jiang**)
[image]

While the real design is now this:
[image]

I don't remember when the change happened, but think it needs to be updated in that page too. :)

[Comment everywhere wiki page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment):
The "What happens when I comment?" section needs an update to the change in the `@` system.

[Create community-wiki posts page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki): (**done it myself now**)
Screenshot is outdated.

[Vote up questions and answers page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up):
Maybe it's worth to mention that only Registered Members can do that?

[Flag posts page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts):
Need lots of work... screenshot outdated plus description of available options.
"How many flags do I have?" section also need to be updated.

[Edit questions and answers page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit):
Missing the associated badges.

Would have done more, but have limited time plus not enough experience here so I leave this to your trusted hands. :)

Please let me know who done what so I keep this post updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the wiki's master, which can be [found on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to include a new screenshot. It should be pushed out to all other sites after a while. The change came about to remove the jQuery UI slider dependency as per Jeff's comment here: [Could we make the new flagging dialog draggable maybe?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/could-we-make-the-new-flagging-dialog-draggable-maybe/75282#75282)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that "wiki master" thing! Can anyone change that page at will?

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you have more than 2k reps on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66242/privilege-wikis-we-need-your-help

Comment: Cheers, the "Temporarily" is already half a year.. wonder how long it will still last? ;-)

Comment: Well, just noticed the "flag posts" wiki also need serious update, both screenshot and description as there are totally different options now. Don't have time to do that myself ATM.. :(