# Close Box Movable

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New flagging dialogue gets in the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/new-flagging-dialogue-gets-in-the-way)

Can we make the close box movable? Sometimes when ensuring that a question is marked as a duplicate, it is nice to be able to compare the actual text with the proposed duplicate question. You can't do that unless you close the dialog box and re-open it again.

Comment: Good idea, but you can also open another tab in the browser

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/could-we-make-the-new-flagging-dialog-draggable-maybe

Comment: @GUI: Are you serious? LOL "Don't make my software easier to use, you're a lazy user"