# Move, box (flag box)

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The new flagging dialog gets in the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/the-new-flagging-dialog-gets-in-the-way)

The flag box can't be easily moved.

[image: move, box]

If you're writing about a post, you really need to be able to move the box around (so you can see what you're writing about), without having to x out and reopen.

Comment: FYI, formatting doesn't work on custom flag reasons =)

Comment: You have an awesome handwriting on the PC, are you using a tablet?

Comment: A Wacom, no less!

Comment: I *just* realized what your hand-written text was referencing.  Awesome =)