# Slider on careers site is a perfect example of David Platt's latest column

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The slider to select how far from your desired location you'd like to look on Careers 2.0 is an irritant; it should at least allow you to enter a number. Clicking/dragging is jerky/jumpy/imprecise. When I want 30 miles, I get 40 or 50.

[image]

Comment: I clicked on this expecting to find a link to David Platt's latest column...

Comment: There seem to be too many "David Platt"s to figure out which one is being talked about.  Are we talking about the director, the pastor, or the soccer player?  I'm not sure which of those would be the one to write about finicky UI elements.

Comment: There's a David Platt blogging on MSDN, so we can probably assume that's who he's talking about. If this is the correct blog, [his latest post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721604.aspx) is something about using fancy widgets to try to impress users instead of designing things well. Clay may be suggesting that a simple textbox would be a better solution.

Comment: That's because you can never get enough jQuery (or in this case, jQuery UI). For the record, I would prefer a textbox too.

Comment: Reminds me of the old bounty slider. Jeff [was not its biggest fan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/the-new-flagging-dialog-gets-in-the-way#comment182490_75282).