# Please remove console.log from stub.js

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, drag-and-drop

The new draggable flagging dialog generates a load of JS errors in IE because in stub.js on line 32 you have `console.log` for coordinates on mousemove. Would be nice if you removed that from the release version of stub.js.

(Turns out in IE `console` is undefined until you summon the developer tools by pressing F12.)

Comment: Draggable flagging, whaa? What did I miss!?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Some [latest changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166398/147640).

Comment: @Andrew: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/the-new-flagging-dialog-gets-in-the-way

Comment: @Mat and GSerg Ahhh... ok; thanks! (as a comment in the Latest changes notes, it's not immediately obvious it's draggable. But I can see how that would be helpful; I often have to close the dialog to see something again.)

Comment: Okay, how many of us are now flagging this question just to be able to drag the dialog?

Comment: @Bart Not only that; I am posting this comment while having the flag dialog up! ;)

Comment: Interesting. You can have as many flag dialogs as you want when you drag them somewhere else before clicking flag again. I have 7 flag dialogs open now while writing this comment.

Comment: I recently got bitten by this on my own site. Stupid IE

Comment: I'm tagging this `status-reproduced` *in spirit!*

Comment: The problem I have with the draggability of the flag/vote/dialog is that the drag hotspot isn't obvious without, of course, dragging your mousepointer over it. It'd be nice if, since the dialog is obviously emulating a regular OS dialog, there was an actual title bar. Or something. Just something visually compelling.

Comment: My boss always bugs me when I leave `console.log` debugging statements lying around :)

Comment: @J.Steen: Well, there *is* some sort of titlebar there...I'd be more happy if the dialog would be dragable from all of the whitespace, though.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby A *visible* title bar. But I like your idea much better. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed a few days ago by another dev.