# "Add comment" button no longer working on any Stack Exchange site for Internet Explorer 8

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, javascript, internet-explorer

Today at 12:30 PM CST, the "add comment" button stopped working on any Stack Exchange site for Internet Explorer 8. It cites a javascript error.

(Edit: I'm not using Compatibility Mode, and JavaScript *is* enabled.)

---

@MartijnPieters - I can only use IE8 at work. It has worked fine until today.

@Bart - Inherently, no, it is not SE/SO's problem, but it depends on whether or not they want to lose a large amount of users for the next couple of years.

@GSerg - What setup are you using? I'm using IE v. 8.0.7601.17514 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit on a Dell Latitude E6420.

---

Let me make this explicitly clear. The company for which I work, an exceedingly large company with many SE users, does not support any other browser besides IE8. This will not change for the next couple of years.

---

**Error details**

[image: SE Comment Error]

Comment: IE8 is no longer being supported. See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "*The company for which I work, an exceedingly large company with many SE users, does not support any other browser besides IE8. This will not change for the next couple of years."* ... that's not really SO/SE's problem, is it?

Comment: Test test. Works.

Comment: @Bart depends on how you look at things.  If this is true, and, more broadly, if it is the case that there is a statistically significant number of SO/SE users who would normally be using the site under IE8, and as a result of this change will not be using the site (or will not be using it nearly as much) then that might start to be worth considering as an SO/SE problem.  I'm not saying that it is that big a deal, but unless we have usage stats indicating that the number of SE IE8 users is too small to worry about, we shouldn't just dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: Accodring to this page, about 40% of IE users are still on IE8: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @Toomai That's not necessarily helpful here, though, because it doesn't mean that 40% of *Stack Exchange* IE users are on IE8.

Comment: @Toomai http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201307-201307-bar would be a better statistic about IE8 in general, but still doesn't say much about the SE users.

Comment: Still, it's usually a reasonable assumption that the preferences of a subgroup aren't ridiculously different than those of the whole.

Comment: The devs most likely always work with the dev tools of IE open so small wonder they didn't notice this one. :)

Comment: I see it.  will get to it asap.  It's true that we don't officially support IE 8, but this is a minor thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build, which should roll out within a few minutes.  Sorry 'bout that :-(

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your quick response. I wish I didn't have to use IE, but I do.

Comment: I was about to take that, thanks Ben!

Comment: Hi. I suspect that this modification may be something to do with the [Pro-forma comments no longer working](http://stackapps.com/a/4241/876). Do you have any tips on how I could adapt the script - preferably without using timeouts! I'm in the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) (on and off) if you want more info.

Comment: @Ben, when I say 'this modification' I don't mean the fix for this bug, but whatever else was going on at the time...

Answer (score 12):

I feel your pain; the local devs would [allow `console` in production code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167440/147640) from time to time for some reason.

As a workaround, just bring up the IE dev tools by pressing F12. This will define `console` and the button will work.

Comment: This works in IE9 as well.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good temporary fix.

Comment: @called2voyage: FWIW, I wouldn't "accept" this answer, as you're less likely to get the attention of the SE devs.

Comment: @Matt Good point. I wish there was some other way I could credit GSerg without making the issue appear closed.

Comment: @called2voyage: up vote him! regardless, meta rep is worthless :).

Comment: @Matt It's not, how else would I go about seeing deleted stuff!

Comment: Great workaround!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using IE9 and clicking the "add comment" link on this question does nothing.

Same for answers.

This workaround described in [GSerg's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190188/167443) appears to work to get past the issue.

I've notice this also applies to the "show more comments" link.