# Did SE change something that caused the pro-forma comment script to stop working?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, scripts

I noticed today that the [pro-forma comments userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) created by [Benjol](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130064/benjol) stopped working. Instead of the nice "auto" button next to the "add comment" button there is nothing:

[image]

[image]

There hasn't been an update to the script recently and it doesn't appear that any resources aren't loading, so I (and [some others](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)) were wondering if maybe SE changed something (maybe with the DOM?) that would cause the script to stop working.

Comment: Perhaps it did; but perhaps it is the job of the script author to fix this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 3rd party script. Ask on the StackApps.com page for this script instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That could very well be, but it would still be nice to know what changed.

Comment: I'm sure the author can debug this quite quickly; post a report here: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Again, I'm not asking how to fix it. I'm asking what changed on SE's part since I'm pretty sure this happened because of something they changed. I realize this isn't their problem to fix.

Comment: Sure, I understand you are curious. That's why it I believe this to be off-topic.

Comment: FWIW: http://stackapps.com/a/4241/10013

Comment: @Seth, I sure wish it [was](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/formal-adoption-of-pro-forma-comments-script-into-se-engine-proper) their problem to fix!

Comment: Probably [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190183/130064)