# Edit reject dialog is not movable

Tags: feature-request, design, rejected-edits

I've noticed that the suggested edit dialog cannot be moved by dragging the top border.

[image]

<s>Is this bydesign? or just overlooked?</s>

Can we have it draggable as well? I sometimes want to have another look at the edit I'm rejecting before I select a reject reason.

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/the-new-flagging-dialog-gets-in-the-way it's by design: _" the flagging and closing popups will be dragable (the "title" at the top is the handle in both cases)."_